# Joomla To Google Play Inetgration

Tags: google-play, joomla3.0

I have a website which provides free books and poetry. I also have an android app for it which shows the contents of the site on the app.

I want my website visitors to download my app from Google Play when they are visiting via mobiles.

For example if you visit www.babycenter.com via mobile phones it will tell you to download their app right on top of the page.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: Please visit ketabkhana.com

I need a module or component.